# Reuse same function body for multiple type signatures

Tags: haskell

I have a function like so:

```
test :: [Block] -> [Block]
test ((Para foobar):rest) = [Para [(foobar !! 0)]] ++ rest
test ((Plain foobar):rest) = [Plain [(foobar !! 0)]] ++ rest
```

`Block` is a datatype that includes `Para`, `Plain` and others.
What the function does is not particularly important, but I notice that the body of the function (`[Para [(foobar !! 0)]] ++ rest`) is the same for both `Para` and `Plain`, except that the constructor used is the type of `foobar`.

**Question**: is there someway to concisely write this function with the two cases combined?
Something like

```
test :: [Block] -> [Block]
test ((ParaOrPlain foobar):rest) = [ParaOrPlain [(foobar !! 0)]] ++ rest
```

where the first `ParaOrPlain` matches either `Para foobar` or `Plain foobar` and the second `ParaOrPlain` is `Para` or `Plain` respectively.

Note that `Block` can also be (say) a `BulletList` or `OrderedList` and I don't want to operate on those. (edit: `test x = x` for these other types.)

The key is that I don't want to replicate the function body twice since they're identical (barring the call to `Para` or `Plain`).

I get the feeling I could use `Either`, or perhaps my own data type, but I'm not sure how to do it.

---

**Edit**
To clarify, I know my function body is cumbersome (I'm new to Haskell) and I thank various answerers for their simplifications.

However at the heart of the problem, I wish to avoid the replication of the `Para` and `Plain` line. Something like (in my madeup language...)

```
# assume we have `test (x:rest)` where `x` is an arbirtrary type
if (class(x) == 'Para' or class(x) == 'Plain') {
    conFun = Plain
    if (class(x) == 'Para')
        conFun = Para
    return [conFun ...]
}
# else do nothing (ID function, test x = x)
return x:rest
```

i.e., I want to know if it's possible in Haskell to assign a constructor function based on the type of the input parameter in this way. Hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: I answered--and deleted that answer-- below suggesting a `Functor` instance for `Block` which is a little boneheaded since `Block` isn't even of the right kind.

Comment: Note that your madeup code is longer and less clear than your Haskell code.  Code reuse is good, but clarity and consiseness are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a (polymorphic) helper function, e.g.:

```
helper ctor xs rest = ctor [ head xs ] : rest

test :: [Block] -> [Block]
test ((Para xs):rest)  = helper Para xs rest
test ((Plain xs):rest) = helper Plain xs rest
test bs                = bs
```

Note that `Para` and `Plain` are just functions of type `[whatever] -> Block`.

Comment: My aim in the question is to avoid replicating the `test (Para ..) = helper Para ...` and `test (Plain ..) = helper Plain ...` lines, since they're the same except for the Para/Plain substitution. Having the helper function does reduce the redundancy quite a bit though (thanks!). I guess it looks like it can't be done in Haskell?

Comment: This is the best balance of the closest to what I was after, and what I am able to understand (being new to Haskell), and helping me avoid replication. cheers

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a data type declaration in the form:

```
data Block
    = Para { field :: [Something] }
    | Plain { field :: [Something] }
    ...
```

You can simply use a generic record syntax:

```
test :: [Block] -> [Block]
test (x:rest) = x { field = [(field x) !! 0] } : rest
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23228c4960cd6e35)

Comment: Will this work of `Block` also has other sub-types (like `BulletList`) that I want to handle separately?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee What do you mean by "sub-types"?

Comment: As in, `Block` can be a `Para`, `Plain`, `BulletList`, .... and I want to handle the `Para` and `Plain` identically but for all others just pass through as-is. Not sure if it helps but the definition for `Block` is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.8.2/docs/src/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#Block)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Just pattern match the others first.

Comment: So I write a number of lines `test (BulletList x) = BulletList x`, one for each of the other options?

Answer (score 1):

First note that, as user5402 already wrote, you should replace `[Para [(foobar !! 0)]] ++ rest` with `Para [foobar !! 0] : rest`, which looks already a good deal nicer. Next note that basically, all you're doing is modify the head of a list, so as a meaningful helper I'd use

```
modifyHead :: (a->a) -> [a] -> [a]
modifyHead f (x:xs) = f x : xs
modifyHead _ [] = []

test = modifyHead m
 where m (Para foobar) = Para [head foobar]  -- `head` is bad, but still better than `(!!0)`!
       m (Plain foobar) = Plain [head foobar]
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax with the simplifications (I'm quite new to Haskell)!. But the main point of the question is that I want to avoid replicating the two `m (Para foobar)` and `m (Plain foobar)` lines for ease of future editing (they are identical except for the type).

Comment: I see your point, but this thinking doesn't really work out. "Identical save for the type" doesn't make sense; if two things have different types then they're about as different as it gets. Still, there is one trick you can employ...

Comment: ... namely, a Rank2-generic modifier. See my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as nice as I can get it without using Template Haskell or Data.Data :-)

First of all, we need to enable some extensions and fix the `Block` datatype for concreteness (if my simplifying assumptions are wrong, tell me and I'll see what can be salvaged!)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, LambdaCase #-}
data Block = Para [Int]
           | Plain [String]
           | Other Bool Block
           | YetAnother deriving (Show,Eq)
```

The important point here is that `Para` and `Plain` are unary constructors, but that the datatype itself can contain constructors with a different number of arguments.

As @leftaroundabout and @user5402 explained, we can separate the concerns of modifying a single `Block` and applying that modification to the first element of a list only, so I'll focus on rewriting

```
modifyBaseline :: Block -> Block
modifyBaseline (Para xs) = Para [xs !! 0]
modifyBaseline (Plain xs) = Plain [xs !! 0]
modifyBaseline rest = rest
```

Next, we need to be able to talk about unary constructors as values. There are 3 important things here:

- does a value match a given constructor,
- if so what values are 'inside',
- and how can we (re-)construct such a value.

We package this up nicely in a custom type (`t` is the type the constructor belongs to, and `a` is what's inside):

```
data UnaryConstructor t a = UnaryConstructor {
    destruct:: t -> Maybe a
    construct :: a -> t
}
```

So now we can define

```
para :: UnaryConstructor Block [Int]
para = UnaryConstructor (\case { Para ns -> Just ns ; _ -> Nothing }) Para
plain :: UnaryConstructor Block [Int]
plain = UnaryConstructor (\case { Plain ss -> Just ss ; _ -> Nothing }) Plain
```

(You can get rid of the `LambdaCase` extension if you write `(\xs -> case xs of { Para ns -> Just ns; _ -> Nothing})` but this way it's nice and compact!)

Next, we need to 'package up' a unary constructor and the function to apply to the value contained in it:

```
data UnaryConstructorModifier t where
    UnaryConstructorModifier :: UnaryConstructor t a -> (a -> a) -> UnaryConstructorModifier t
```

so that we can write

```
modifyHelper :: [UnaryConstructorModifier t] -> t -> t
modifyHelper [] t = t
modifyHelper ((UnaryConstructorModifier uc f):ucms) t 
    | Just x <- destruct uc t = construct uc (f x)
    | otherwise = modifyHelper ucms t
```

and finally (the lambda could have been `(\xs -> [xs !! 0])` or (`\xs -> [head xs])` to taste):

```
modify :: Block -> Block
modify = modifyHelper [UnaryConstructorModifier para (\(x:_) -> [x]), 
                       UnaryConstructorModifier plain (\(x:_) -> [x])]
```

If we now test it with

```
ghci> let blocks = [Para [1,2,3,4], Plain ["a","b"], Other True (Para [42,43]), YetAnother ] 
ghci> map modify blocks == map modifyBaseline blocks
```

we get `True` - hooray!

---

The repetitive bit is now in the definitions of `para` and `plain` where you have to write the name of the constructor three times, but there's no way around that without using Template Haskell or Data.Data (that I can see).

Further options for improvement would be to do something for constructors of different arity, and to put a function of type `a -> Maybe a` in `UnaryConstructorModifier` to deal with the partiality of `(\(x:_) -> [x]`) but I think this answers your question nicely.

I hope you can make sense of this, as I've glossed over a couple of details, including what's going on in the definition of `UnaryConstructorModifier` and the use of pattern guards in `modifyHelper` - so ask if you need clarification!

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to your original idea is probably a "generic `Para`-or-`Plain`-modifying" function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
modifyBlock :: (forall a . [a]->[a]) -> Block -> Block
modifyBlock f (Plain foobar) = Plain $ f foobar
modifyBlock f (Para foobar)  = Plain $ f foobar
```

Observe that `f` has in each use a different type!

With that, you can then write

```
test (b:bs) = modifyBlock (\(h:_) -> [h]) b : bs
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty nicely with `ViewPatterns`

*Note: view patterns isn't actually required here, it just makes it looks a bit nicer imho*

*Note': This assumes the list inside the block is of the same type in both cases*

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
paraOrPlain :: Block a- > Maybe (a -> Block a, a)
paraOrPlain (Plain xs) = Just (Plain,xs)
paraOrPlain (Para xs) = Just (Para,xs)
paraOrPlain _ = Nothing

-- or even better

para (Para xs) = Just (Para,xs)
para _ = Nothing

plain (Plain xs) = Just (Plain,xs)
plain _ = Nothing

paraOrPlain' b = para b <|> plain b -- requires Control.Applicative

test ((paraOrPlain -> Just (con,xs)) : rest) = con (take 1 xs) : rest
```

Of course you still need to do the pattern matching somewhere - you can't do that generically without TH or Generic - but you can do it in a way that lends itself to reuse.